# How to make a relative div span its absolute content?

Tags: css, css-position

Very basic question here, but it has been puzzling me for hours:
How do I make a relatively positioned div span its absolutely positioned content?

http://jsfiddle.net/X6ay2/10/

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can seeing that `position:absolute` takes the element out of the document flow, but I could be mistaken

Comment: @Shaun You also couldn't account for `left`/`right` positioning of the content with CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly really, as absolute positioned elements are out of the document flow and so don't really 'belong' to their parents anymore. A kind of workaround though is to set the absolute positioned div to 100% width and left:0, which will force it to extend to the width of the parent.

```
.outer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X6ay2/14/

A caveat to this is if the inner div has padding, it will extend beyond 100%. To stop this, make the inner div use the border-box box-sizing property.

```
.inner {
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X6ay2/15/

Answer (score 0):

set width of the outer to suit your needs.  The example has

```
 width:50px
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X6ay2/12/